# why is having (or excluding) 'www' in the URL affecting how my site displays to users?

Tags: html, http

I am cleaning markup on a website for my first customer. I did not build the site; I want to remove the table-based design and replace it with proper CSS, before I add a shopping cart to the site.
http://www.theresheglowsdayspa.com

I noticed by accident that the appearance will change if 'www' is removed from the URL.

Can someone explain what's going on here? Also, is there a best practice with 'www' or no 'www' in the URL?

Comment: It's because on your server, you haven't configured it to work (you need to add an entry for the server to associate that name with the specific site). You'll need to specify what server you are running on, and it can be easily fixed.

Comment: Seems to look the same for me, regardless of the `www` subdomain. I'm using Chrome 7.0.517.36 on Ubuntu 10.10, if it matters.

Comment: Looks same on the latest version of Opera.

Comment: The 'bug' appears only in Firefox.

Comment: @user2485: could you plz be more specific?! What are the differencies (at least describe one) you are seeing when displaying site with/out 'www'. Anyway the site layouyt is a piece of junk, it shows tons of validation errors, and each page displays the menu differently. Whether using 'www' or not it should be your last concern here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `www` or not is debatable for aesthetic reasons - however cookies and other same domain policy stuff attached to a example.com will affect something.example.com, however www.example.com will affect itself only.

There could also be stuff like server side code that assumes the presence of www in the URL.

There could also be rules for a server such as Apache that handles things differently.

Comment: When you mentioned cookies it gave me the idea to test other browsers. This problem only occurs on Firefox 3.6, and looks the same on IE and Chrome. I still don't know why but at least I know its a Firefox issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the links in the side menu.

they strip out the www and show a full domain link.
you could linke them as:

this would shorten the url, and would work in both www. and non www requets.

here is how i usually do it:
i like all my assets from  
it may be a bit longer, but keeps things cleaner in the long run.

Then i use a URL Rewrite script to redirect all non www to www.  This is for SEO purposes because google sees www.yoursite.com and yoursite.com as two seperate sites.

If you are using IIS its simple to do with URLRewrite, apache has something called mod rewrite.